# I can't make SublimeREPL run Python 3, instead it's running Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

As you can see from the following code: I am trying to run a simple
code that checks the python version and takes the user's input:

```
import platform  
print(platform.python_version())      
msg = input("Hello, how are you? ")     
print(msg)
```

We know that Sublime doesn't take any user input in a default fashion, so that's why I installed SublimeREPL, the inconvenience that I'm having is that an error arrises when I run the code above in SublimeREPL:( The code runs fine (apart the fact that it can't take input) in Python 3.6.4 (As I intend) in the normal part of Sublime Text 3:

```
3.6.7
Hello, how are you?
```

But when the code is ran in SublimeREPL it displays that the code is being ran in Python 2.7.10, therefore the error occurs:

```
2.7.10.   
Hello, how are you? Good   
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "first.py", line 3, in <module>    
    msg = input("Hello, how are you? ")   
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   
NameError: name 'Good' is not defined    

    ***Repl Closed***
```

The only way that the string input will work in the SublimeREPL is if I use raw_input() or use quotes around the input, but they're very inconvenient and they're a hassle.
Can someone provide me a solution in having SublimeREPL run in python 3.6.4? I've tried to look for a solution everywhere online, but nothing seems to be working.
Btw I'm using a Mac, I just switched from Windows, and it worked fine on Windows I remember.
Thanks.