# Receiving NameError on input in SublimeREPL

Tags: python, sublimerepl

I'm trying these lines in Python 3 using SublimeText:

```
a = input('Geben Sie bitte das Wort "Hallo" ein: ')
if a == "Hallo":
    print('Korrekt!')
```

Now if I run that in SublimeREPL I get

```
Geben Sie bitte das Wort "Hallo" ein: Hallo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S79.py", line 1, in <module>
    a = input('Geben Sie bitte das Wort "Hallo" ein: ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Hallo' is not defined

***Repl Closed***
```

However, it works if I [run it online](https://repl.it/languages/python3).

I don't quite get it. In SublimeREPL it only works if I type

```
'Hallo'
```

instead of

```
Hallo
```

Any suggestions?

==========
Update: So I did further dig into this problem, and I am starting to think that SublimeText uses Python 3 YET SublimeREPL runs my code in Python 2. For instance, raw_input produces an error in the same script if I build it but makes it work in SublimeREPL instead. Further evidence for that problem to exist I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714752/i-cant-make-sublimerepl-run-python-3-instead-its-running-python-2). Is that even possible and how can I change that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sublime, but it looks like you're actually running it in Python 2, not Python 3. For details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15129556/4518341). There should be a setting that lets you change that.

Comment: In SublimeREPL, what does `import sys; print(sys.version)` return?

Comment: @wjandrea I already considered that possibility, but my SublimeREPL-->tools-->build system is set to Python 3.

Comment: @MattDMo  3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:10:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]